# Ubuntu is not listed on the GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I installed Fedora23 on a GPT partition(also chose LVM option).

There is no option now for Ubuntu on the GRUB list when I boot normally (without interfering).
However, if I hit F9 on bootup and go into boot options, I see

```
Fedora(Toshiba MQ01...)
Ubuntu(Toshiba MQ01..)
Boot From EFI File
```

I can boot from here to Ubuntu by selecting Ubuntu or going into the EFI(grubx64.efi).

I ran `update-grub` from Ubuntu.
I also followed the instructions from [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Install_the_bootloader_files).

When I run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, I can see Ubuntu 14.0.. on /dev/sda5

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz....
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.....
Found Ubuntu 14.04... on /dev/sda5
```

But I don't have an Ubuntu option to boot.
What can I change to have the options for both Fedora and Ubuntu?

**Edit**
As suggested by *clearkimura*, I ran update-grub in Fedora first.

Comment: Generic advice: The boot loader on the first partition (or where it was installed at first time) should be updated, and *not* the boot loader in other partitions. Here, I assume Fedora was installed first? Then boot loader in Fedora should be updated instead.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file (Ubuntu might relocate it to somewhere in /boot/efi/, not 100% sure as Ubuntu isn't my speciality)?. Also, what partitions are each of the distributions on?